# Running multiple threads concurrently with ExecutorService but only executed a few

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have an application that basically will run multiple threads at the same time using ExecutorService but somehow it only got executed some of them. In this example I submitted 30 tasks to a pool of 10 threads but it only executed around 20 tasks. Was there anything wrong with my code?

I already put some sleep duration to wait but still no better luck. Should I run it as ScheduledThreadPool?

Here are my codes:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(int i =0;i<30;i++) {
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        String firstName = faker.name().lastName(); 
        RunningThread run = new RunningThread(firstName.toLowerCase(), s3, gcs, amazonIam, googleIAM, false, projectName, 1);
        System.out.println("run thread "+ i);
        executor.submit(run);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }
    System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");
```

Here is the Thread implementation:

```
public class RunningThread implements Runnable {
    String name;
    AmazonS3 s3 ;
    Storage gcs;
    AmazonIdentityManagement amazonIam ;
    Iam googleIAM ;
    boolean companyReg;
    String projectName;
    int employeeType;

 public RunningThread(  String name, AmazonS3 s3, Storage gcs,  AmazonIdentityManagement amazonIam, Iam googleIAM, boolean companyReg, String projectName, int employeeType) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.name = name;
        this.s3 =s3;
        this.gcs = gcs;
        this.amazonIam = amazonIam;
        this.googleIAM = googleIAM;
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
        this.companyReg = companyReg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long duration = 0;

        try {
            //          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(companyReg == true) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                duration = MainApplication.registerCompany(s3, gcs, amazonIam, googleIAM, name, projectName);
                }else {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                duration = MainApplication.registerNewCfBEmployee(s3, gcs, amazonIam, googleIAM, name, projectName, employeeType);
            }
            MainApplication.duration.add(duration);
            System.out.println(duration);
            Thread.sleep(30000);

        } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: "but somehow it only got executed some of them" - Can you explain this?  You're submitting 30 tasks to a pool of 10 threads, but you haven't stated a question.

Comment: @JacobG. Sorry forgot to put the question. I submitted 30 tasks to a pool of 10 threads but it only executed around 20 tasks. Was there anything wrong with my code? I suppose that when it runs all 30 of them should be running

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a small snippet of code that we can compile?

Comment: You don't understand; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are shutting down the executor as soon as you finish submitting tasks

Comment: @Nadir please read the documentation of shutdown method. This is not the problem.

Comment: you say you submitted 30 tasks but only "around 20 tasks" were executed. How do you know that? From the code you have posted, basically you can just tell one of two things: Either "finished all threads" is printed, in which case all 30 tasks must have been exectued. Or you don't get that printed at all, in which case the tasks are still running or queued.